# svn credentials over http [Linux]

Tags: linux, apache, http, svn, credentials

I have a svn running over HTTP. However, I have no idea where the credentials are for setting up users and passwords. Since it's not using the svn:// protocol, svnserve.conf and passwd are useless.

So I need to know where credentials are configured.

Oh, I am able to checkout if you were wondering. But any credentials I use in RapidSVN give me an authentication error.

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

It was a htpasswd file.